# Sending a link in an email

Tags: php, gmail

Ok before you guys laugh LOLZ --> I'm not sure if this is a GMAIL issue or something I'm doing wrong but im trying to insert an email for an activation link in the body of a message.

```
$body = "Or click on this link: <a href=\"http://www.url.com/start/page.php?verify=true&id=".$url."&activate=".$ac."> Activate Your Account </a>"
```

**Ok the problem here is that my GMAIL account shows this: (which BTW is click-able and routes correctly)**

```
Or click on this link: <a href="http://www.url.com/start/page.php?verify=true&id=f22645cff5ecfd4d3c115af5&activate=75845> Activate Your Account </a>
```

What am I missing here? Is this just a gmail issue? How can i Correct this?
I want it to show: **Activate Your Account**

Comment: Are you sending the email as an HTML email? What are the headers?

Comment: You are not sending an HTML email (or you are doing it incorrectly.).

Comment: Ahh didn't know I had to specify -- How do I send as an HTML email?

Comment: [The answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510795/how-to-send-an-email-with-an-html-element-here-is-my-code-its-working-however) has the necessary headers. [There are many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+send+html+email)

Comment: @JaredFarrish that didn't change anything.. Same result

Comment: Then your problem is what @MichaelBerkowski has intimated; eg, you have to set the email to be interpreted as HTML, not plaintext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wrong Syntax,

error hould have showed you whats happening,

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line x...
```

2 . Send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set to html

I made some changes and tested this, try this working script :

```
<?php
$body = 'Or click on this link: <a href="http://www.url.com/start/page.php?verify=true&id='.$url.'&activate='.$ac.'"> Activate Your Account </a>';
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail("to@gmail.com","Subject goes here",$body,$headers);
?>
```

[PHP Mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

Comment: Ok i got your code to work - but adding a subject line breaks it? Whats the deal? and Its not showing my email address but my SERVER name instead... any ideas?

Comment: Just edited the code, You need to send from in the header, and Subject would be 2nd argument for mail function.

Comment: Yeah i got it working earlier but thx. I checked u reciprocate if so inclined :)

Answer (score 3):

Try closing the quote at the end of your URL.

The SO syntax highlighting even showed you the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For sure you're missing a double quote here.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/...5845>
```

This shall be instead written as:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/...5845">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't set the headers, this works for me. Of course you need to set your own variables.

```
                $sender_email = strip_tags($sender_email);
                $subject = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode(strip_tags($title))."?=";
                $message = nl2br(strip_tags($message));
                $headers = "From: ".$sender_email.' <'.$sender_email.'>'."\r\n";
                $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;\r\n";
                $headers .= "\tformat=flowed;\r\n";
                $headers .= "\tcharset=\"utf-8\";\r\n";
                $headers .= "\treply-type=original\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
                $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$sender_email."\r\n";

                $body =  __('sendfriend:defaultmessage') . '<br /><br/><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'" target="_blank">'.$link.'</a><br/><br />'.$message;
                $mail = mail($recipients, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to send the email as an HTML email.

```
$headers = "From: myEmail@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
mail(...$headers);
```

Add the $headers variable on the end of the mail function.

Answer (score 0):

define headers in your mail function first

```
  $headers = 'From: abc@example.com' . "\r\n" .
  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```